# Type synonym for lambda-based/church booleans

Tags: haskell, lambda

Assume that true (`t`) and false (`f`) are defined as follows:

```
> let t = \x -> \_ -> x
t :: t1 -> t -> t1
> let f = \_ -> \y -> y
f :: t1 -> t -> t
```

Is there a way to define a type synonym that can capture the type of both boolean values?

Comment: The type of the Church-encoded booleans would be `forall a. a -> a -> a`. It cannot be specialised to either the type of your `t` or `f` but that's not surprising: their type leaks information about the boolean they represent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that [Church Booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans) basically either choose the first or the second parameter, and you want to use them in something like

```
if' :: Boolean -> a -> a -> a
if' b tval fval = b tval fval
```

such that

```
if' t 1 0 == 1
if' f 1 0 == 0
```

you have to restrict the type to a single type variable `a`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

type Boolean = forall a. a -> a -> a
```

Here's an [article that covers Church Booleans in Haskell in detail](http://statusfailed.com/blog/2014/09/23/church-booleans-in-haskell-and-morte.html).